# In Python, how can I loop over all the matches of a regular expression on a string?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I want to do something (more than just substitution) with substrings matching a pattern in a longer string. If an assignment were an expression returning a value, as in C and most other programming languages, this would be (using C syntax with Python semantics):

```
  while ( match = re.search( pat, str ) ) {
       /* do something to the string, using the match object,
          in addition to removing or replacing the substring
       */
    }
```

or more verbosely, avoiding the use of an assignment as an expression:

```
for ( match = re.search( pat, str );
      match;
      match = re.search( pat, str ) ) {
   /* do something to the string, using the match object */
}
```

At least one of these is possible in most programming languages: C, C++, Java, Perl, Javascript, ... but neither of them seems to be possible in Python. Is there a pythonic equivalent (not involving a kludgey mess with a break or continue statement)?

Comment: The answer depends. What are you looping over? There is definitely NO one to one mapping, but there certainly are pythonic equivalents. If you can be a bit more precise with what you want... because as it stands this question is too broad.

Answer (score 9):

You may be looking for [finditer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer):

> Return an iterator yielding match objects over all non-overlapping matches for the RE pattern in string. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

s = "abcabcabc";
it = re.finditer("(\w)", s)
for m in it:
    print(m.groups())
```

```
 $ ./t.py
('a',)
('b',)
('c',)
('a',)
('b',)
('c',)
('a',)
('b',)
('c',)
```

Comment: This only scans the string once, so it won't work in the general case; almost any change to the string inside the loop will break it, for example replacing the matched pattern by something which has a different length.

Comment: Maybe you can given an example which illustrates the behavior you want and ask how to implement it in Python. I am not willing to play "guess what the OP wants".

Comment: To be fair, the OP writes `do something to the string, using the match object,` inside the loop.

Comment: @PatrickT Quoting exactly, the OP says "_I want to do something ... **with** substrings_" (emphasis mine) "with" is not the same as "to" ... specifically, doing something **with** substrings does not automatically imply modifying the underlying string. ... Then, in the comment, the OP switches to "to", but it is not clear what is meant by that. If one wants to derive a new string from the old, one can do that without inplace replacements. The question remains unclear.